# Add column to datatable and bind it in grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a gridview with property `autogeneratecolumn=true`
and my DataTable is filling the data as mentioned below using mdx query.

```
sales2015   sales2014
1256           1235
3569            0
0              1235
```

i want to add another column named "VARIENT" and need to show the percentages in the same.

> Formula: `(sales2015 - sales2014)/sales2015 * 100`

Need to calulate each row for the datatable using same formula and bind to gridview.

please help me with the logic.

> Note : my grid is having autogenerated columns

expected result is like this

```
sales2015   sales2014  Varient
1256           1235      **%
3569            0         **%
0              1235      **%
```

My Code part is:

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
ViewData1 vData = new ViewData1();
dt = vData .__getCustomerSource()// Here in this function i was filling the datatable and returing

DataGrid1.DataSource = null;

DataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: How did you generate the grid View? Show the code for the query. You could add the formula for each item in a row in the grid View and get the desired result.

Comment: will you please give me any example to do that like

Comment: I do not know how you are populating your grid view.

Comment: i have posted the code please look into that

Comment: before bindng i want to do this task

Comment: @sowmya: Use any stored procedure or function to fill the required data and then assign to grid view

Comment: i was filling datatable with MDX query

Comment: please find me the solution in code behind before binding the grid]

Comment: In the Query itself pass the required fields and get the required data.

See this example Conditional MDX Query to calculate sum and average

Comment: i have the MDX query which is not relevent with your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the third column on the fly and populate it like this:-

```
dt = vData .__getCustomerSource()
dt.Columns.Add("Varient", typeof(string));
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
    row["Varient"] = String.Format("{0} %", ((row.Field<int>("sales2015") - 
                        row.Field<int>("sales2014")) / row.Field<int>("sales2015")) * 100);
 }
DataGrid1.DataSource = dt;
DataGrid1.DataBind();
```

You need to change your formula accordingly.

**Update:**

If your column names will be changing then you can make use of column index (but as you know it may fail if your datatable structure change dynamically) like this:-

```
(int)row.[1] - (int)row[2]
```

Comment: thanks for your solution..  my columns names will be changing every time based on the user inout if he selects data from 2012 column name changes as sales2012 and sales2013 so i need the code based on the index not not the column names

Comment: @sowmya - Check my update, I hope your column index will remain fixed otherwise you can't do this.

Comment: row["Varient"] = String.Format("{0} %", ((int)row.[4] - (int)row[2]) / ((int)row.[4]) * 100);  i have used this code it is showing error identifier expected

Comment: @sowmya - I hope you are writing your code in Visual Studio, it's one of the best IDE :) Anyways you have `.` between `row.[4] `

Comment: @sowmya - Did this worked for you? You haven't updated anything.